# Getdate(), -1 day

Tags: sql, sybase, sqlanywhere

I do not understand why, but somehow this query doesn't work.
I want to take system date -1 day where the sysdate is smaller by 1 day then current date.

```
WHERE
    a.SEND_Date >= dateadd(DD,-1,(CAST(getdate() as date) as datetime))
```

Comment: What does "doesn't work" look like?

Comment: Do you actually need the `CAST` there?

Comment: I am not sure if that CAST is necessary.
That's why I am asking help to make this better or fix this query line.

Comment: I figured that maybe this way is even better
DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,-1,GETDATE()),-1)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The CAST depends on what kind of date type you need.
If you need only to compare dates you can use only:

```
dateadd(DD, -1, cast(getdate() as date))
```

If you need to compare with date time you can use:

```
dateadd(DD,-1,getdate())
```

That wil give you  datetime like this: `2016-01-11 10:43:57.443`

Answer (score 16):

In T-SQL (sqlserver) you can simply do :

```
getDate()-1
```

The function substracts (days) as standard.

Comment: This will be a DATETIME value, with hours and minutes, not a DATE value which is just year/month/day.

Answer (score 7):

Or you can try this without making it any more difficult?

```
 CAST(GETDATE()-1 as date )
```

Answer (score 0):

The checked answer still has time (00:00:00), in my version anyway. 
To  get DATE only use:
Select Convert(date,dateadd(day, -1, getdate()))

Both have same weight, 0.001 seconds

Answer (score 0):

There's just one CAST missing:

```
dateadd(DD,-1,(CAST(getdate() as date) as datetime))
```

two times "as" (as date + as datetime) but only one time "CAST" => something wrong - should be:

```
dateadd(DD,-1,CAST(CAST(getdate() as date) as datetime))
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Don't follow any as this date will come issue on 01/05/2020 will print as 00/05/2020. So kindly use this below for the fix

```
select CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(DAY, -1, convert(Nvarchar, GETDATE(),112)),112)
```