# SQL convert varchar to date and add 30 days to the current date

Tags: sql, date, casting

I have 3 columns that are defined as `varchar` and should be dates. They show up as Date1: 20171029, Date2: 20171027, Date3: 2017028. I want to convert them to 17-10-27. I also want to filter Date3 between 21-01-01 and Today + 30.

```
SELECT
    first_name,
    last_name
    date1,
    date2,
    date3
FROM 
    Data;
```

I have not tried to change the `varchar` to date yet.

I have tried to use CAST to filter the dates between 21-01-01 and today+30. It doesn't filter the dates.

```
SELECT
    first_name,
    last_name,
    department,
    date1,
    date2,
    date3
FROM 
    Data
WHERE 
    department = 'accounting'
    AND (CAST(date3 AS Date) >= (GETDATE() - 730) 
         AND CAST(date3 AS Date) <= (GETDATE() + 30));
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Your query is using product specific functionality.)

Comment: *It doesn't filter the dates.* Does it return anything? If yes, what? If not, does it return error? What error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getdate(), -1 day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34738836/getdate-1-day)

Comment: There is no error. It just returns the same data and doesn't filter the dates.

Comment: Shmiel. I am not sure what the -1 day means. Do I replace -730 with -1? I am new to SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Convert` and `DateTime`:

```sql
SELECT
    first_name,
    last_name,
    department,
    date1,
    date2,
    date3
FROM 
    Data
WHERE 
    department = 'accounting'
    AND
    Len([date3]) = 8
    AND
    Convert(DateTime, [date3], 112) 
        Between '2021-01-01' 
        And DateAdd(Day, 30, DateDiff(Day, 0, GetDate()))
```

Comment: I get an error: conversion failed when converting date and or time from character string

Comment: Some of the date3 has all 0's in it. I think that is why I am getting the error. How do we put N/A to replace all the 0's?

Comment: Filter out invalid values. See modified answer, please.